# Downloading app content using airtel 4g LTE wifi is very slow in ios application

Tags: ios, xcode5, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

In my application i am downloading content frequently from a server and saving the content (images, videos) in persistent storage (documents folder). Here the problem is when i am using a dedicated wifi with 2Mbps speed download completes in 10mins, but if i am using Mobile carrier 4g LTE wifi for the same content it is downloading very slowly (taking more than 30 mins) even though the speed is 20Mbps.

**Content is nearly 200mb**

Can some one please tell why this is happening

Comment: Could be a lot of things - could be that the carrier has a very slow route, or they are throttling the download. I don't think it would be anything specific to the code in your iOS application.

Comment: @vcsjones But if i am using the same wifi for my macbook, the download is very speed..